# Just finished writing the Vanity Plates assignment under CS50. Would like to know if there's a way to make it more efficient

Tags: python, cs50

Code works and I've submitted it already. However, I had a difficult time trying to make it more concise.

```
def main():

    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if length(plate) and check_firstnum(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def length(s):

    if (2 <= len(s) <= 6) and s[0:2].isalpha() and s.isalnum():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_firstnum(n):

    for char in n:
        if char.isdigit():
            index = n.index(char)
            if n[index:].isdigit() and char != 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    return True

main()
```

Comment: Without knowing the functional criteria it's hard to say whether your code will even produce the correct results, let alone do it efficiently

Comment: If the code works, this is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com Please also read its relevant help center pages like ['What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)'

Comment: Note that this code does *not* meet the requirements of the exercise. One of the rules is, "the first number used cannot be 0". That means a plate like `CS05` is invalid, because the first number that occurs in the plate is `0` (but your code returns `Valid` in this case). See the test cases [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/2/plates/) for some other test suggestions.

Comment: It would be better to name the `length(plate)` function `check_length(plate)`.

Comment: @jarmod ...except that the *length()* function doesn't just check the length

Comment: If you want to be really clever, a lot of this could be done with a regular expression.  But then you'd have [two problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/1997).

Comment: @CtrlZ fair enough. My comment was largely that the function doesn't calculate the length so it shouldn't be called length(x). Maybe check_len_charset(x) would be better, or split into 2 check_xyz functions.

Answer (score 1):

For something so trivial it's probably not worthwhile writing discrete functions for the individual tests.

Be aware of the difference between *str.isdigit* and *str.isdecimal* the latter being preferred in this case.

Just do it with "straight line" code like this:

```
def is_valid(plate):
    if not 2 <= len(plate) <= 6:
        return False
    if not plate[:2].isalpha():
        return False
    if not plate.isalnum():
        return False
    for i, c in enumerate(plate[2:], 2):
        if c.isdecimal():
            if c == "0":
                return False
            if not plate[i:].isdecimal():
                return False
            break
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    print("Valid" if is_valid(plate) else "Invalid")
```

**Note:**

Probably out of scope for this but worth noting that *"²".isalnum() == True* whereas *"²".isdecimal() == False* and *"²".isdigit() == True*. Same applies to all other superscript digits. This means that with the code above any superscript digits in the input will **not** be treated as numeric

Comment: It's also worth noting that `isalnum` and `isalpha` don't care if you're using English letters or something else, so this will report something like "김세정" as a valid license plate. But oddly enough, the [RMV itself](https://www.mass.gov/how-to/request-a-vanity-license-plate) is not explicit about the valid character set  , so not something we need to worry about.